# .htaccess RewriteRule causing "file not found"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My website is hosted in a subfolder : `site.com/foo/`

In the root of the `foo/` folder I have the following `.htaccess` :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It's role is to redirect all page requests to a `webroot/` subfolder located within the `foo/` folder.
In that `webroot/` subfolder, I have the following `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

The goal is that all should be redirected to that `index.php`. To be clear, file structure is :

```
www/
  foo/
      .htaccess
      webroot/
         .htaccess
         index.php
```

When I try accessing `site.com/foo/`, I get `index.php` as expected, but when I try random things such as : `site.com/foo/bar/bar/bar`, I get "file not found"(that's all) but I sill wanted `index.php`.

The reason it works only when accessing `site.com/foo/` has nothing to do with the second `.htaccess`, it's just `webroot/` serving its contained index.php by default.

Notice : it worked in `localhost`, and the main difference between `localhost` and the server I'm using now is probably that the site was in `ROOT` for `localhost` but within a subfolder now (`foo/`).

Notice 2 : If I remove `/$1` from `index.php/$1`, it works, it redirect ALL to index.php, but without the parameter which I need (`bar/bar/bar` in the above example.)

How can I get all request to be redirected to that index.php with parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `RewriteBase` in both .htaccess:

**/foo/.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo/

RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

**/foo/webroot/.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo/webroot/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What is the full URL in browser and what error did you get?

Comment: The URL is "site.com/foo/bar/" and what I get is "file not found". It looks for that url without going through index.php

Comment: To test change rule in `/foo/.htaccess` to `RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L,R]` and then load `site.com/foo/bar`

Comment: This redirects to (secret)/www/foo/webroot/bar ... it really seems it doesn't take index.php into account

Comment: why is there `/www/` before `/foo/`? I thought your web root is `/www/`

Comment: What do you mean? `/www/` is indeed the web root that's why it is before `/foo/` (which is located within the `/www/` webroot). The "secret" part above is not my webroot but the server specific path.

Comment: If `/www/` is `DocumentRoot` then URL must not have `/www` and URL should have been `http://domain.com/foo/webroot/bar` instead of `http://domain.com/www/foo/webroot/bar`. btw I have no idea why you mean by `(secret)` in URL. URL should start from `http://` and then you can mask your real domain name like my examples.

Answer (score -1):

QSA flag appends the query string-

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?data=$1 [QSA]